# How Gen 31:39 relates to Gen 43:9

Tags: genesis, hebrew

In Hebrew, these two passages sharing the same idiom in a very unique similarity, and I would like to know what is the reason.

In Gen 31:39 speaks of Jacob who was very righteous in taking responsibility of the cattle of Lavan. If one sheep was killed by accident, he would pay it from his salary.

> “...אנכי אחטנה מידי תבקשנה...” (בראשית 31:39)

In Gen 43:9 Judah takes responsibility for bringing back Benjamin.

> “אנכי אערבנו—מידי תבקשנו...” (בראשית
> 43:9)

Comment: I am not sure what question you ask here.  Apart from both using the same verb, חָטָא, what is your question?  This same verb occurs about 238 times in the OT.

Comment: It is not about the חטא, it is about this format of four words that begins with אנכי, and ends with מידי תבקשנה

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an interesting observation of yours. I think it also links with Genesis 37:

*26 And Judah said unto his brethren, What profit is it if we slay our brother, and conceal his blood?
27 Come, and let us sell him to the Ishmeelites, and let not our hand be upon him; for he is our brother and our flesh. And his brethren were content.*

And:

*31 And they took Joseph's coat, and killed a kid of the goats, and dipped the coat in the blood;
32 And they sent the coat of many colours, and they brought it to their father; and said, This have we found: know now whether it be thy son's coat or no.
33 And he knew it, and said, It is my son's coat; an evil beast hath devoured him; Joseph is without doubt rent in pieces.*

There is a contrast between righteous Jacob and Judah. Israel did pay for torn animals from his own pocket. His son sold his younger brother which he supposed to protect (like a good shepherd does with his flocks) and laid to his father that Joseph was torn by a beast to cover it. Genesis 43:9 is the beginning of Judah redemption. I think that the writer purposely used similar vocabulary to link it with the story of Jacob and the selling of Joseph to give more depth and background to Judah's actions.

Comment: Excellent point of view! Very good andwer! I will wait for other opinions

Comment: More than that: Why did Jacob decided to send Benjamin with Judah, and not with Reuben, or not at all? And why he was so aftaid to send Benjamin?